# Europa Universalis IV: Keeping Army Tradition HIgh

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I just did a difficult economical-challenged achievement (Lucky of the Irish as kildore).

It was difficult in the early years to keep army tradition higher than 10-25ish Army Tradition.

I was wondering is there an easier first 4 at most idea group order that can reach at least 50ish army tradition hovering ignoring National Ideas (Like Prussian .5 bonus to Army Tradition).

Requirements:

+Two military ideas in three or four first idea groups at most

+possible use of policies is ok

+Assuming western tech group country

+assume National Idea will not contribute one way or another to army tradition

+stuff that indirectly reduce boost army tradition like building cost and less maintenance is ok

+Assume growing tall gameplay with few war or mostly defensive mentality

+reach hovering 50 army tradition or higher

+assume this country will either start small or medium (One province up to 30ish) and grow to afford +1/2 advisers across the board

+idea group obviously have to be practical like second idea is military to avoid falling behind

+ideally doable before 1600 (Thirty Years' War)

+fewer monarchy points used the better

I know it is possible to reach 100% hovering (did it for an achievement) but it requires lot of idea group picks to be practical in every possible situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duh, I already could figure out the answer myself. I will post here for anyone else who are curious.

At the most you only need 1200 military monarch points + lot of admin to unlock the third idea group slot.

With updated one fort per each 50 development. You get one army tradition per month.

With defensive and quality. You get two army tradition per month from each. Be sure to pick another diplomacy or admin idea group in between.

No policies necessary.

With decay of 5 percent each month. You will hover at 60 army tradition.

Monthly army tradition divide by decay percent = hovering army tradition.

3/.05 = 60

Comment: Regarding the hovering AT, I just did the math out of curiosity. Stable condition is `(x+3)*0.95 = x`, solving this for x yields `x = 3*0.95/0.05`, not `3/0.05` as you wrote. The difference is very small, of course (this would only be significant if the decay were larger). Just nitpicking!

Comment: The point of my equation is that "this X" is required to have enough monthly army tradition to not lose any each month. BTW solving for your equation gives 5.7 which isn't 60. I supposed if you time by 10 and subtract one month worth of Army tradition then it would be correct.

Comment: By 5.7, do you mean 57? That should be the right result

Comment: Look like I insert an extra zero by accident in front of .95 when I did my math. I still like my equation since it account for the monthly decay one way or another.